# Zombie Threads on POSIX systems

Tags: multithreading, posix

How do zombie threads get formed in C/C++, and what do you need to make sure to do in order to prevent them from being created?  I know they're just normal threads that didn't terminate properly, but I'm a little hazy on the specifics.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A zombie thread is a joinable thread which has terminated, but which
hasn't been joined.  Normally, either a thread should be joined at some
time, or it should be detached.  Otherwise, the OS maintains its state
for some possible future join, which takes resources.

Comment: Adding to the answer, a terminated thread must be joined by another thread in order to be recycled and a detached thread must be explicitly cancelled (pthread_cancel) or exited (pthread_exit) in order to get recycled.

Comment: @ArnuMu A pthread is automatically exited when the function that it calls returns.  (I can't remember ever using `pthread_exit`.  And `pthread_cancel` can be tricky, and doesn't guarantee that the thread will terminate.

Comment: You are right regarding thread auto exiting when returned. And I use it (depending upon mood :) ). But I dont agree with you on your comment about unreliability of "pthread_cancel". Can you provide some link  as proof ?

Comment: I have come across this nice link : http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/pthread_cancel.3.asp

Comment: @ArunMu The Posix standard.  `pthread_cancel` requests cancellation, it doesn't force it.  Cancellation can only occur at specific places in the code; it can be blocked by `pthread_cancel_state`, or in certain system requests, and it calls cleanup handlers, which don't necessarily finish (and the cancel will only terminate the thread once they've finished).  Terminating a thread is a complex issue, and sometimes `pthread_cancel` is necessary, but it is never sufficient; the thread has to cooperate.

Comment: :Agree now on the fact that pthread_cancel may be unsafe in a situation where a thread calls a library which is not cancellation aware and blocks the cancellation signal thus preventing the cleanup handler from executing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean pthreads or zombie processes? A zombie process (not thread) gets created when a parent doesn't reap its child. It's because the OS keeps the return state of the process if the parent needs it later. If the parent dies, the child is given to the init thread which just sits and calls "wait" over and over again (reaping any children that die). So a zombie process can only be created when the parent is still alive and the child has terminated.

The same applies for pthreads. If you detach the thread, it will not keep that process termination state around after it finishes (similar to processes).